# Delay loading of script in dom by N seconds

Tags: javascript, settimeout

After my site loaded, I want to delay the below javascript for 10 seconds

**script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="io258wer15cfg789as69th07er64hziq" src="//mysite.domain.com/script.php?id=io258wer15cfg789as69th07er64hziq" defer></script>
```

**i tried this** but not working:

```
<script 
    setTimeout(
      function(){ 
        type="text/javascript" 
        id="io258wer15cfg789as69th07er64hziq" 
        src="//mysite.domain.com/script.php?id=io258wer15cfg789as69th07er64hziq" 
        defer } 
    ,10000)>
</script>
```

Comment: Insert that `<script>` in dom by using `createElement`.

Comment: @KalpeshSingh if that's an answer, it would be nice to just write it as one

Comment: i have the similar issue and i tried this [js_timing](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: I have same kind of situation, i am using a chat tool which integrate with our site to help visitors online and on the spot. but i will have to delay the chat widget to be appear after 10 seconds once the entire web site loaded.

Comment: is any option to set the timeout, can anyone have tried, please help me to accomplish this

Answer (score 3):

You need to add it using createElement. So that it will inject after 10s.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  setTimeout(addScript, 1000)
});

function addScript() {

  script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.async = true;
  script.onload = function() {
    console.log("Added Script");
  };
  script.src = 'https://foo.com/bar.js';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: This is only part of the answer. Note that OP wants this script to only be delayed **after** the DOM has loaded

Comment: Thank you, Updated. @Alerts do you need explanation or is it good enough?

Comment: I would argue that `DOMContentLoaded` is not quite the same as "My site loaded", but close enough

Comment: @KalpeshSingh I tried this code in my Site and the code itself displaying in the site after the footer of the site and the my script is loading immediately, i am not sure weather i am replacing my script correctly,

Comment: Possible to share URL for testing?

Comment: sorry, The server is accessible only from LAN, not exposed to the internet.  the script which i added in the question is the exact one i am using currently. it is a livezilla chat tool script to integrate with the site.

Comment: any tries on this post, please help to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.onload = function() {
  window.setTimeout(function () { 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.id = 'io258wer15cfg789as69th07er64hziq';
    script.src = '//mysite.domain.com/script.php?id=io258wer15cfg789as69th07er64hziq';
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(script);
  }, 10000);
};
```

Comment: OP wants this script to only be delayed **after** the DOM has loaded

Comment: How about something like [`window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load)? Less intrusive than assigning a function ref to the onload

Comment: My script is not getting loaded here, my script contains a chat widget which will display at the bottom of my site. so i am trying to delay that after my page gets loaded